# Trying to access using a function my $connection variable to a database located in a different directory

Tags: php, sql, database

As the title says, I have a database connection file in a different directory and im trying to access that inside a function, it works if its not inside a function as I have been using through out my web development, but now that I need to access inside a function it does not work.

```
 function getSubCat($mainCat){
    include"../sql/sqln.php";
    $sql = "SELECT SUB_CAT FROM CATEGORIES WHERE CAT = '$mainCat' GROUP BY SUB_CAT";
    $getQuery = $connection->query($sql);
}
```

`PHP` storms points out this `error`. unidentified variable '`connection`'

Database connection

```
    <?php
       session_start();
       $username = "xxx";
       $password = "xxxx";
       $database = "xxx";
       $localhost = "xxxx";
       $connection = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password, $database);
?>
```

UPDATE:

I tested it and the function is actually working, but PHP storms still give me an warning/error (unidentified variable 'connection'). not sure if I should just ignore it since its actually working.

Comment: it looks like it's unable to include the `sqln.php`. Is the path correct?

Comment: I can include it just outside the function, but inside the function it doesnt work

Comment: Thats really weird... I just tested it with some random functions. It works perfectly..

Comment: it's either the path is incorrect or `mysqli_connect` is erroring out for some reason.

Comment: I will have a look again, maybe its just PHP storms giving an warning.

Comment: I tested it and the function is actually working, but PHP storms still give me an warning/error. not sure if I should just ignore it since its actually working.

Comment: @Luke Yeah ignore it. If you really want to test your code, always run it on a server and only look at the error reporting of PHP. Don't take errors from your IDE too serious, since they tend to have some problems with includes.

Comment: @Twinfriends yeah I will do that.

Answer (score -1):

Send the $connection variable as a parameter:

```
function getSubCat($mainCat,$connection){
    include"../sql/sqln.php";
    $sql = "SELECT SUB_CAT FROM CATEGORIES WHERE CAT = '$mainCat' GROUP BY SUB_CAT";
    $getQuery = $connection->query($sql);
}
```

and when you call the function do it this way:

```
getSubCat($mainCat,$connection)
```

Comment: If i do this way I no longer need to include the path inside the function? As if I call the function somewhere else its likely that I will be including the path in that area in order to pass the connection variable.